# xsetwacom on elementary OS Hera?

Tags: release-hera, package-management, wacom

I'd love to use [xsetwacom](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-xsetwacom/) to look into some wacom issues & features. For example improving the usability with multiple monitors. But I can't find or install it.

Following:
https://medium.com/@microaeris/setting-up-wacom-tablets-with-ubuntu-16-04-d7277e4a595d
I have `libwacom2` and `libwacom-common` already installed, but I can't install `xserver-xorg-input-wacom`:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-wacom                              
[sudo] password for peteruithoven:       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The suggested changes when trying to install `xserver-xorg-core` seemed like a bad idea:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core                        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libxatracker2 libxvmc1 x11-apps x11-session-utils xinit xinput xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  xfonts-100dpi | xfonts-75dpi
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  elementary-desktop xorg xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xserver-xorg-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 16 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
Need to get 1351 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5291 kB disk space will be freed.
```

What is the way to install xsetwacom on elementary OS Hera? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i have `libwacom-bin/dev/common`, `libwacom2` and `xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04` installed, and the xsetwacom is on the system.

Comment: Thanks! Installing `xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04` instead of `xserver-xorg-input-wacom` works. I can now use xsetwacom.